# When is lock from pg_try_advisory_xact_lock released exactly?

Tags: postgresql

> pg_try_advisory_xact_lock works the same as pg_try_advisory_lock, except the lock, if acquired, is automatically released at the end of the current transaction and cannot be released explicitly.

Does that mean the lock is released immediately before transaction is committed and visible to other processes or immediately after the transaction is committed?

I wanted to know if there is a potential for a very small race condition if I query in a 2nd transaction for *data from 1st transaction* **OR** *is lock obtained in 1st transaction* and not get any of them?

Comment: A transaction ends _after_  a commit as finished successfully. When exactly should "before" the commit be? A second? A millisecond? A nanosecond?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about mili/nanoseconds. Whether it is implemented in Postgres internally as (release locks, transaction visible to others) or (transaction visible to others, release locks). Perhaps there is a critical section in postgres implementation around those two and the distinction does not make sense.

Comment: I believe it should not be (release locks, transaction visible to others) because then 2nd transaction could obtain the lock and not see what the 1st one did, which would make the lock a bit useless for implementing critical section inside my own app.

Comment: I don't understand the question. And advisory lock has nothing to do with visibility of data. In fact an advisory lock is not used by Postgres at all to do anything. It is only _managed_ by Postgres so that your application can use it. But any lock (be  it an advisory or a "regular" lock) is released after the transaction _ends_. Not a nanosecond before that.